# Confusion on SPFileVersionCollection and SPListItemVersionCollection

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I have 17 versions on a file uploaded into a document library. When I use `SPFileversionCollection`, I get 16 versions, while `SPListitemVersionCollection` shows 17 versions.

I think `SPListItemVersionCollection` contains draft version whereas the other one `SPFileVersionCollection` contains only published version.

But why there is a difference in number of returned versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SPListItemVersionCollection` object **contains all the versions**, including the current one.

The `SPFileVersionCollection` object **does not include the current version**.

[Documents and versioning](http://www.itidea.nl/index.php/documents-and-versioning/)